# Is there a way to concatenate three two-dimensional vectors along the Column in C++ like the way in python:np.concatenate([x,y,z], axis=1)?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I am trying concatenate two-dimensional vector in C++ like the python:

```
np.concatenate([x,y,z], axis=1)
```

I tried the below code but it concatenates along the row.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> dest{{1,2,3,4,5}};
std::vector<std::vector<int>> src{{6,7,8,9,10}};

dest.insert(
  dest.end(),
  src.begin(),
  src.end()
);
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

But I am expecting it be like the below:

```
1 6
2 7
3 8
4 9
5 10
```

Is there a workaround to do the concatenation along the column as above python `np.concatenate` function?
I am trying to visualize the data so I need to transpose all the vectors and concatenate along the column.

Answer (score 1):

You can use newmat11 to achieve a phyton like behavior described: http://www.robertnz.net/nm11.htm

```
std::vector<int > dest{ 1,2,3,4,5 }; 
std::vector<int > src{ 6,7,8,9,10 };
std::vector<int> third{ 11,12,13,14,15 };
Matrix x(5, 3);
x.column(1) << dest.data();
x.column(2) << src.data();
x.column(3) << third.data();
Matrix sub = x.submatrix(1, 5, 1, 2);

std::cout << sub << std::endl;
```

Produces the following output

```
1.0   6.0
2.0   7.0
3.0   8.0
4.0   9.0
5.0  10.0
```

A Matrix stores its values consecutive, so you can get your single vector like this:

```
std::vector<double> merge(sub.Store(), sub.Store() + sub.size());
for (auto& digit : merge) std::cout << digit << "\t";
```

Which produce the following output:
1 6 2 7 3 8 4 9 5 10

The "hardest" thing to do is:

1. Download all required .h and .cpp files from the homepage
2. Create a new project consisting of the newmat11 files
3. Build to .lib
4. Add reference, include directory and .lib path to your main project